# Is the statement is True or False?

Tags: general-topology

Is the following statement correct or incorrect?

Let $X $ be a topological space and $W \subset X$. Then, the induced subspace
topology on $W$ is the smallest topology such that $$\text{id} | _{W} : W \rightarrow X,$$ where $\text{id}$
is the identity map, is continuous.

My attempt : I was taking $ X $ with usual topology  and $W$ with lower limit topology, and I take $ f(x) = x.$ Then 
$$\text{id} |_W : W → X$$ will not continuous because lower limit topology is  finer than  the usual topology, so the map will not be continuous.

Is my answer correct or not? I would be  thankful who will verify my mistakes.

Comment: What do you mean by induced Topology then ? In your example $X $ has usual Topology, and $W$ has lower-limit Topology !! Is lowerlimit Topology the induced Topology on $W$ ,induced from the usual Topology !!

Comment: Little english remark about comparatives : "finer" is enough ; "more fine" could be correct, but not "more finer".

Comment: It is confusing saying "$X$ with the usual topology and $W$ with the lower limit topology" without saying $X=\mathbb{R}$ (and I cannot guess what $W$ is).  In any case, some textbooks define the induced topology on a subset $W$ of $X$ to be the smallest topology such that the inclusion $i:W\to X$ is continuous.

Comment: What you stated is jumbled.  The subspace topology is the induced topology by id, the smallest topology for which id is continuous.  Your attempt misses the point.  You know what the subspace topology is.   Now describe the induced topology.  If U is an open subset of X, what is id^-1(U)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is **true**. Recall that the subspace topology on $W \subseteq X$ induced from $(X,\mathcal{T}_X)$ by definition equals $\mathcal{T}_W = \{O \cap W: O \in \mathcal{T}_X\}$.

This topology makes $i: W \to X$ defined by $i(x) = x$ continuous, because $$i^{-1}[O] = O \cap W$$ for all subsets $O$ of $X$, in particular for open ones. ($x \in i^{-1}[O]$ iff $x \in W$ and $i(x)\in O$ iff $x \in W$ and $x \in O$ iff $x \in O \cap W$).

And if $\mathcal{T}$ is any arbitrary topology on $W$ such that $i: (X, \mathcal{T}) \to (X,\mathcal{T}_X)$ is continuous this forces that $i^{-1}[O]$ are in $\mathcal{T}$ for all $O$ in $\mathcal{T}_X$.
This just says that $\mathcal{T}_W \subseteq \mathcal{T}$, proving the claim that the subspace topology is the smallest (or coarsest) topology on $W$ that makes $i$ continuous.

Comment: thanks a lots @ henno Brandsma ,,,but im not getting the line i(x)  ∈ O if x∈ W and x ∈ 0 iff x∈ 0∩W..

Comment: @Jameslegolegoh I'm giving a short proof of the identity. I use the definition  for the inverse image under $i : W \to X$: $i^{-1}[O]  = \{x \in W: i(x) \in O\}$, then I use $i(x)=x$ and the last is the definition of intersection.

Comment: thank u so much,,im getting now @Henno Brandsma